# Replace 3 X LR44 battery requirement with a single AAA or AA battery

Tags: batteries, conversion

I have a rowing machine that requires ("eats," more like it) three LR44 batteries. I'd like to replace that battery requirement with something more common and rechargeable. I've made a career from writing very complex software, but am seriously in the dark about electronics so I do not know where to start with figuring out how to make this conversion.

Where can I go to learn the basic knowledge I'd need to figure this out? Even better, if someone has done this before and can share notes?

Many thanks...

Comment: I have seen NiMH button cells but I am not sure how you would charge them. I guess there must be button cell chargers out there. Also, I am not sure if they are the exact same size as your LR44 cells. And NiMH has slightly lower voltage than alkaline. So there is a chance that the rowing machine won't like them. All in all, it would be better to frankenstein a 3 cell AA or AAA holder to the rowing machine, as Chris suggested.

Comment: Follow Chris's suggestion. A cheap source of battery holders is the small strings of LEDs. You want one with the AAs. You'll just have to figure out the polarity.

Comment: It annoys you because you're spending too much on them.  First, make sure you're buying alkaline, not silver oxide.   You don't need the stability of silver oxide and they're costing you $$$.   And don't buy them retail - Batteries have a ludicrous markup -   Here's a link to buy 50 of them for about 10 cents each.  https://www.ebay.com/itm/50-X-AG13-LR44-LR1154-SR44-A76-357A-303-357-Alkaline-Coin-Cell-Button-Battery/183760281890?hash=item2ac8f76122:g:W8MAAOSwFe5X0yn6

Comment: True enough, @KyleB. The cost is annoying. Perhaps more so is the hassle of changing the batteries. They aren't exactly easy to get at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get these convenient battery holders with switch for cheap from the usual electronics sites (just search "battery holder"). Pick one with the correct number and types of batteries.

[image]

Since LR44 is alkaline, AAs or AAAs are a one to one replacement.

Solder the wires, in correct polarity, to the springs that make contact to the LR44. Or you could just strip the wires and twist them around the springs, then insert something in the battery compartment to hold them in place... like the old LR44s with some tape on them to prevent them from being "recharged" by the voltage from the AAAs.

Comment: This is working perfectly. The one change is that rather than tape the three LR44s together, I used a piece of 3/8" wooden dowel cut down to be a little shorter than the thickness of 3 LR44s. This was necessary because the thickness of the 3 LR44s + connectors I'd attached to the battery case wires were too thick to fit into the rowing machine's battery compartment.

Answer (score 1):

An LR44 is basically just a smaller version of an Alkaline flashlight cell.

So what you'd really need would be to graft a holder for 3 AAA or AA cells to the back of the control panel.

To use a single one, you'd need a boost converter, and that's likely to waste power without really sophisticated integration with the thing being powered.

Comment: This is good news. I've ordered a 3 X 1.5V AA battery holder. Figuring out how to graft it to the control panel will be an interesting task. I'll report back on the end result.

Answer (score 0):

Replace with AAA, it is difficult to find the battery that I needed. I decided to just go with this plan as they are cheaper, the AAA.